# How to create valid lambda predicate from two expressions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have following entity model:

```cs
public class SortableEntity {
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public int IntProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

And following failing test case:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task TestExpression()
{
    Expression<Func<SortableEntity, long>> expression1 = e => e.Id;
    Expression<Func<SortableEntity, int>> expression2 = e => e.IntProperty;

    var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SortableEntity, bool>>(
        Expression.And(
            Expression.Equal(
                expression1.Body,
                Expression.Constant(123L)
            ),
            Expression.GreaterThan(
                expression2.Body,
                Expression.Constant(456)
            )
        ),
        expression1.Parameters[0] // not sure what should go here
    );

    await _db.SortableEntities.Where(predicateLambda).ToListAsync();
}
```

It throws following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SortableEntity>
    .Where(s => s.IsDeleted == False)
    .Where(s => s.Id == 123 & e.IntProperty > 456)' could not be translated.
```

I guess the problem is in `s => s.Id == 123 & e.IntProperty > 456`, one expression is using `s` variable name and other `e` variable name. How I can make it work so both expressions use same variable name?

Comment: You can also use the [ReplacingExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-5.0) class from EF Core. But the principle is one and the same.

Comment: Gah, I'd just written an answer for the question above.  You don't need the visitor, you just need to build up the property-selecting expressions correctly.